# Targeting Penguin's Bird Cages

Tags: batman-arkham-origins-blackgate

Every time I come across one of the bird cages in Arkham Origins: Blackgate, it drops on me and I take damage. I looked it up and it appears you can use your batarangs to take them down from afar, therefore avoiding damage.

I can't seem to target them, and when I throw a batarang, Batman just throws it in a horizontal line. Am I missing something, or is it some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On continuation of the game I have discovered that to interact with objects using your gadgets, you must have first scanned/analysed them in detective mode.

Once you have scanned a bird cage, it will become targetable with your batarangs. This also applies to Joker Teeth, Black Mask's masks, vents, circuit breakers and wooden piles/weak wooden barricades (with the respective gadgets).